# Deepin refuses to use laptop screen without HDMI connected

Tags: desktop, hdmi, deepin

When I boot Deepin 15.7, it for some reason seems to refuse to show anything onscreen without a HDMI connection - even if the screen's off.

NOTE - It shows GRUB, then when I select Deepin and log in, the cursor does a load and then the screen switches off until I connect HDMI.

I suspect it's in the settings, since it began when I was messing and rotated the screen.

EDIT: Here's the `~/.config/startdde/display.json` config

```
{
  "eDP343f3a0f165a07b1e6f43f9e3f474d1d": {
    "Name": "",
    "Primary": "eDP-1",
    "BaseInfos": [
      {
        "UUID": "eDP343f3a0f165a07b1e6f43f9e3f474d1d",
        "Name": "eDP-1",
        "Enabled": true,
        "X": 0,
        "Y": 0,
        "Width": 2880,
        "Height": 1620,
        "Rotation": 2,
        "Reflect": 0,
        "RefreshRate": 59.96025750906705
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: @Rui You deleted the last part, without it this would be a duplicate

Comment: I doubt it will won' t be even with it, but feel free to add it. I usually advise keeping on topic and keep it shorter. You seem to have added some technical data, congrats.

Comment: @Rui Will or won't? (Not clear)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine when I set `~/.config/startdde/display.json` :

```
{
  "My Settings 1+eDP343f3a0f165a07b1e6f43f9e3f474d1d,HDMI20cde46b179d940d99eb2a8cbbe8eb43": {
    "Name": "My Settings 1",
    "Primary": "eDP-1",
    "BaseInfos": [
      {
        "UUID": "eDP343f3a0f165a07b1e6f43f9e3f474d1d",
        "Name": "eDP-1",
        "Enabled": true,
        "X": 0,
        "Y": 0,
        "Width": 3200,
        "Height": 1800,
        "Rotation": 0,
        "Reflect": 0,
        "RefreshRate": 59.99977415600772
      },
      {
        "UUID": "HDMI20cde46b179d940d99eb2a8cbbe8eb43",
        "Name": "HDMI-1",
        "Enabled": false,
        "X": 3200,
        "Y": 0,
        "Width": 1920,
        "Height": 1080,
        "Rotation": 1,
        "Reflect": 0,
        "RefreshRate": 60
      }
    ]
  },
  "eDP343f3a0f165a07b1e6f43f9e3f474d1d": {
    "Name": "",
    "Primary": "eDP-1",
    "BaseInfos": [
      {
        "UUID": "eDP343f3a0f165a07b1e6f43f9e3f474d1d",
        "Name": "eDP-1",
        "Enabled": true,
        "X": 0,
        "Y": 0,
        "Width": 2880,
        "Height": 1620,
        "Rotation": 0,
        "Reflect": 0,
        "RefreshRate": 59.96025750906705
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It seems the display reverted to this, and I change `"Rotation"`to `0` not `2`, effectively undoing what I did previously. I also disabled HDMI, but it works fine with it on